# Pandas - Read/Write to the same csv quickly.. getting permissions error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, io

I have a script that I am trying to execute every 2 seconds.. to begin it reads a `.csv` with `pd.read_csv`. Then executes modifications on the df and finally overwrites the original `.csv` with `to_csv`.

I'm running into a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` and from my searches I believe it's due to trying to open/write too often to the same file though I could be wrong.

- Any suggestions how to avoid this?
- Not sure if relevant but the file is stored in one-drive folder.
- It does save on occasion, seemingly randomly.
- Increasing the timeout so the script executes slower helps but I want it running fast!

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling `read_csv`?  With a filename (a string) or an an open file object?

Comment: filename/string

Comment: Just right click on your file and check the attribute. If it's 'read only' then unmark it and try again.
Hope this helps

Comment: Also check by right-click on file-> properties then clicking on security tab and check the permissions of the file.I think the problem is with the file and not the code.

Comment: my idea is explicitly reading the file contents and closing it before the rest of script, unless the file is very big. how do you invoke the script every 2 sec, externally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't share your exact code, we can only assume that you store your dataframe like this:

```
df.to_csv("myfile.csv", sep = ",", index = False)    # Drop to csv w/o context manager
```

In this case, the behavior you are experiencing is due the file not being closed properly. This is a common mistake. I recommend to use the `with`-[statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), whose primary use is an exception-safe cleanup of the object used inside (in this case your `.csv`). In other words, `with` makes sure that files are closed, locks released, contexts restored etc.

```
with open("myfile.csv", "w") as reference:           # Drop to csv w/ context manager
     df.to_csv(reference, sep = ",", index = False)
# As soon as you are here, reference is closed
```

Comment: This is what I was after, thanks. I had to add `encoding="utf-8"` to get it playing nice.

Answer (score -1):

Close the file that you are trying to read and write and then try running your script.
Hope it helps

Comment: It does not, the file is not open.